# Azure Devops yaml - Runtime variable doesn't not behave like compile time variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

In Azure Devops I am using the template yaml loop-template.yml:

```
parameters:
  paths: string

steps :

  - ${{ each path in split(parameters.paths, ',') }}:
  - script: echo "loop template " ${{ path }}
    displayName: ScriptName ${{ path }}
```

which gets a comma-delimited string with paths and tries to iterate through them.

I call this template from another yaml
which is like this

```
variables:
- name: SnykScanPaths
  value: val1,val2

        # it doesn't work
      - template: loop-template.yml
        parameters: 
          paths : $(SnykScanPaths)

        # it works
      - template: loop-template.yml
        parameters: 
          paths : ${{variables.SnykScanPaths}}
```

The results I get are the following

[image]

So even though the compile time variable ${{variables.SnykScanPaths}} has the same value with run time variable $(SnykScanPaths), only the compile time variable leads to proper iteration.

Any idea what can I do with this?
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected.

You must use ${{}} as the structure to get the value, if you use $(), the entire string will be recognized as string by default.

[Parameter Usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script)

> Parameters are expanded just before the pipeline runs so that values
> surrounded by ${{ }} are replaced with parameter values.

So simply put, your first type of usage is not correct.